# How to verify camera distortion values (and intrinsics) from given images

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

This may sound like a bizarre question, but I am stuck and wondering if there is a solution to this problem at all.

I have a set of images recorded from a camera, which I no longer have access to (due to the current situation). The problem is, I am not sure whether the raw images were captured, or whether the undistored/rectified images were captured, since the camera SDK (Zed mini, if anyone is interested) provides both images, and its a matter of choosing which one to output.

Given the images (100 images or so), and given my camera intrinsics (focal length, and cx,cy), is it possible to check whether I have to undistord the images or not? I have the distortion values : `k1`,`k2`,`k3`,`p1` and `p2`, but if the images have already been undistorted, then I do not have to use these values at all.

In a nutshell, is it possible to find out if my images have already been undistorted or not,(for eg. say using OpenCV)

If it is possible, just as a thought exercise since it seems interesting, I was wondering along similar lines, if it is possible to verify whether some camera intrinsics values is right, given a set of images.

Here is a sample image, if that would help
[image]

Comment: how many images do you have and what is their content? If there are lines in the image, from which you know that they are straight in the real world, they would be straigt in the image if the images are already undistorted (or if the line is going through the principal point). So if your image content has some reality-straight-lines at the outer image reagions, you can check easily whether they are distorted or not.

Comment: Hi @Micka the images are merely RGB images, of road data (similar to KITTI if you have come across it) I've edited my question and attached a sample image. I will look into the solution you suggested and find such lines before and after undistorting and see which looks straight. Thanks!

Comment: if there are images driving along urban area, you'll typically find some upright street lamp infrastructure with quite straight real lines in the outer parts of the image. However, the image looks like low/no distortion to me, but hard to tell since the only really known straight lines (the boxes) are close to the image center..

Answer (score 1):

Visually I can say that these images are rectified since I cannot see any distortion in the sides or corners, but since science doesn't work this way, one method to verify this using OpenCV is using epipolar geometry:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html
If your epipolar lines are similar in your image pair, than the images are rectified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe you could also provide a code snippet that implements the check?

Comment: Actually it is at the end of the article https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html

Comment: Sure! The problem with links is that with time they get outdated or even inaccessible. Your answer is more likely to help others if it won't involve going to an external website to look up the specific code.